# Кто такой Сидор и зачем ему коза?

Tags: фонетика, фразеология, пунктуация

Все, наверное, знают выражение "драть как сидорову козу" - безжалостно применять телесные наказания (при этом оттенок у выражения все-таки слегка шутливый). Но вот интересно, кто такой этот Сидор и чем ему не угодила его коза? Что-то я не припомню сказок с такими персонажами. Откуда тогда пошло это крылатое выражение?
И еще интересный момент: я чаще слышал вариант со смещенным ударением - "драть как сидорову кОзу". Почему так?
Ну и последнее: правильно ли я пишу этот фразеологизм без запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По одной из версий, Сидором называли озлобленного человека, вымещающего эмоции на вредном животном, испортившем огород. Другие версии не менее интересны http://shkolazhizni.ru/archive/0/n-23023/
Кстати, я и сам ставлю ударение на первый слог, но почему именно так - не могу ответить... Возможно, это связано с памятью предков.
Да, пишется без запятой этот оборот.